# Exclude term from wp_get_object_terms

Tags: php, wordpress, function, taxonomy

So pretty straightforward, seemingly, but I can't find any examples in either a) the Wordpress Codex; or b) in any examples in the wild. I'm just trying to exclude a term from this output of terms from a custom taxonomy.

I went with wp_get_object_terms instead of get_terms because I have the output needs to be formatted specifically and it seems wp_get_object_terms is the only function that can do the job, although get_terms do have an explicit 'exclude' option. So here's what I'm working with:

```
<?php $taxopostid = $post->ID;
    $taxoquery = wp_get_object_terms( $taxopostid, 'work-type');
    $taxoslug = $taxoquery[0]->slug;
    $taxotitle = $taxoquery[0]->name; ?>

    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/blog-slug/<?php echo $taxoslug; ?>/" class="cat-link"><?php echo $taxotitle; ?></a>
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `worktype` is the taxonomy you want to exclude.

### Step 1

Get all taxonomies excluding `worktype` with `get_terms()` (you know how to do this right?)

### Step 2

With the result make a flat array only containing all the fetched taxonomies (lets call it `$allTaxonomiesExcludingWorkType`)

### Step 3

Add the array as the second argument to

`wp_get_object_terms($taxopostid, $allTaxonomiesExcludingWorkType);`

Not tested but this should help you on your way.

GL

Comment: Nuts, this looked like it would work, but I'm just trying to exclude a term from a taxonomy, not an entire taxonomy. But yes, 'work-type' is the taxonomy.

Comment: Then sorry I don't understand what you mean because I never used taxamonies in this way.
I'm afraid I can't help you any further.